# CSS specificity issue with tables

Tags: css, css-specificity

I can't figure out why the following is happening. (I can - and have solved the problem in an unrelated way.)

**SUMMARY:**

1. I have a table which the rows have alternating styles. Good.
2. I wanted to add a color to show "in progress" and "completed".
3. PROBLEM: The CSS for the alternating row colors keeps trumping my code for "in progress" and "completed".

**MORE IN-DEPTH:**

The HTML code for the table is:

```
    <table class="tbl-invoice">
        <tr class="completed">
            <td>9/21/2014</td>
            <td>PAID</td>
            <td class="rep">Bill Bayer</td>
        </tr>
```

All the styles are in one file.

The CSS for alternating colors:

```
.tbl-invoice tr:nth-child(odd) td { background-color:#F0F8FF; }
```

Its specificity is 0 0 2 2.

The CSS for "completed":

```
.completed { background-color:#e5ffe5; }
```

The above style trumped it. No problem. So I wrote:

```
.tbl-invoice tr td .completed { background-color:#e5ffe5; }
```

which also has a specificity of 0 0 2 2 but is placed BELOW the previous example so this CSS should trump the other.

Not only did it not trump it, but it didn't trump it even when I added `body`:

```
body .tbl-invoice tr td .completed { background-color:#e5ffe5; }
```

Comment: Don't forget about the `tbody` element that browsers include whenever you as the coder forget to include it explicitly.

Comment: @TylerH - thx. Will definitely keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simplifying your even/odd CSS

```
.tbl-invoice tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color:#F0F8FF; }
.tbl-invoice .completed { background-color:#e5ffe5; }
```

Here is a similar [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6kLdyz6g/)

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML doesn't match your CSS rule. Do you want a bg color on the `td` or the `tr` ? If you keep your HTML as:

```
 <table class="tbl-invoice">
        <tr class="completed"><td>9/21/2014</td><td>PAID</td><td class="rep">Bill Bayer</td></tr>
```

Then the css rule should be:

```
.tbl-invoice  tr.completed{background-color:#e5ffe5;}
```

Comment: Thx. .tbl-invoice  tr.completed{background-color:#e5ffe5;} definitely worked. I gave you a +1. I chose Gary's answer as it was the one that clicked. The "trick" so-to-speak was to simplify the CSS. And yes, you gave the same answer.

Answer (score -2):

...if you can't share any code then we can't be sure of the solution, but you can try the direct specifity among the classes using the '>' symbol.

But why not use !important in your class and be done with it?

Comment: most people are looking for quick solutions to their problems to close a project. I still don't understand people's hesitation to use !important and even override it later on using the same thing...

Comment: I solved it my changing the table class name. I'm currently using tbl-invoice for tables which ONLY have alternating colors and tbl-invoice-colors for the others.

Comment: @scooterlord Because here at StackOverflow we do not strive for hacks; we strive for best practices.

Comment: If you are doing it on a really small site or your own site that's fine. The problem is that the ONLY way to override it is to use another !important.  If you set up your CSS correctly, you should (almost) never need to use it at all.  When I am hiring junior developers, if I find it in there code, I won't hire them.  It's lazy, and in most cases, shows a lack of understanding of how CSS works.

Comment: Gary, I totally agree with you, however, it's a matter of the type of the project and most importantly it depends on whether you have all of your templates ready from the beginning. There's no point in spending more space adding classes everywhere if you can override it. Just my opinion.